# Compare id local api with id local db for favorite feature in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localdb, sqflite

I have a problem with favorite feature. How to compare id local api JSON with id local db for favorite feature in flutter?I already try to solve it use sqflite, but i got stuck, because when i try to click favorite, it is not change to add. Here my code :

```
class FlowersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const FlowersScreen({super.key});
    static const String routeName = '/product-flower-grid';
    @override
    State<FlowersScreen> createState() => _FlowersScreenState();
}

class _FlowersScreenState extends State<FlowersScreen> {
    ListAndDetailFlowerModelResponse idProduct = 
    ListAndDetailFlowerModelResponse(
    id: 1,
    urlImage:
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/386015/pexels-photo- 
    386015.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2',
    type: "Bouquet",
    flowersName: "Red Rose",
    availableColors: "Red, Pink, White, Blue, Orange, Purple",
    price: "Rp 300.000;",
    isFavorite: false,
    );

    List<ListAndDetailFlowerModelResponse> _products = [];

  // Code to get list flower
  Future<void> readListFlowerProduct() async {
    final String dataJsonFlower = await readjson.rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/json_file/list_and_detail_flower.json');
    final productListFlower = json.decode(dataJsonFlower);
    var listFlower = productListFlower["productFLowers"] as 
    List<dynamic>;
    setState(() {
      // _products = productListFlower["productFLowers"];
      _products = listFlower
          .map((e) => ListAndDetailFlowerModelResponse.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      for (var i = 0; i < _products.length; i++) {
        if (_products[i].id == idProduct.id) {
          _products[i].isFavorite = true;
          break;
        }
      }
     });
    }
  // End Code to get list flower

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFCECFA),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 39,
                  left: 23,
                  right: 127,
                  bottom: 10,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Ulfa's Flower Shop",
                  style: TitleDetailFlowerScreen().text2,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 23, right: 164, 
              bottom: 32),
                child: Text(
                  "Welcome, Flower lovers..",
                  style: SubTitleDetailFlowerScreen().text3,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: const ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  Color(0xFFEAC0E6),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: readListFlowerProduct,
              child: Text("See Products", style: 
           ButtonProducts().text5),
            ),
          ),
          // ignore: prefer_is_empty
          if (_products.length > 0)
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: const 
           SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 30,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    mainAxisExtent: 160,
                    childAspectRatio: 166,
                  ),
                  itemCount: _products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: const Color(0xFFEAC0E6),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 13,
                              ),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                    DetailFlowersScreen.routeName,
                                    arguments: 
                   jsonEncode(_products[index]),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: 
                   BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    _products[index].urlImage,
                                    width: 107,
                                    height: 102,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // const SizedBox(
                            //   height: 5,
                            // ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 3, bottom: 7, left: 22, right: 
                             19),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    _products[index].flowersName,
                                    style: FlowersNameCard().text4,
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite,
                                      color: 
                         _products[index].isFavorite == true
                                          ? Colors.red
                                          : Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          else
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Card(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text(
                    "Click Button to see our products",
                    style: CardUnderButton().text6,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),
           ],
          ),
          );
          }
```

I confuse to make ListAndDetailFlowerModelResponse idProduct for all my products and show favorite list in my favorite screen..

Comment: Add some code so we can understand

Comment: Sir, I have sent my code. Thank you.